# Marshall Custom Object of type ArrayList using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, arraylist, jaxb, marshalling

I am using `JAXB` to marshal an Object of type ArrayList. I've created a Wrapper class since we cannot Marshal ArrayList directly but still I am getting error.

Class to be Marshaled

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class FindTransactionDto implements IFindTransactionDto {

private String agencyCd;
private String createdDate;
private String custEmail;
private String custPhone;
```

Wrapper Class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class FindTransactionWrapper {

@XmlElementWrapper
@XmlElement(required = true)
private List<FindTransactionDto> findTransactions;

public FindTransactionWrapper() {
    findTransactions = new ArrayList<>();
}

// getters/setters
```

JAXB Marshaling Logic

```
private String processObjectToXML( Object object, String serviceName, String operationType ) throws Exception {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(FindTransactionWrapper.class );

    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty( Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE );

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    marshaller.marshal( object, writer );

    return writer.toString();
}
```

Stack trace

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.util.ArrayList nor any of its super class is known to this context.
```

Comment: So, if i understand correctly, the object parameter in your XML is an ArrayList ?